# Exception Assistant not working

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2010, exception, native

I'm using VS2010 with WPF, C#, CLI and native C++.
When I get an exception in the C# part, I don't see the exception assistant.

It seems that exception assistant is not working, if unmanaged code debugging is enabled.

As I need both, is there a workaround for this problem?

In tools/Options I have checked "Enable the exception assistant".
In project settings I have checked "Enable unmanaged code debugging".

If I uncheck "Enable unmanaged code debugging" the exception assistant is working as excepted.

Answer (score 4):

Whenever I see this it is because VS has decided to disable the "Thrown" option for "Break when exception is" options under the Debug->Exceptions menu item.

I've had this happen multiple times, though I haven't been able to isolate why yet.  When re-enabling the on "Thrown" options I leave the "Common Language Runtime Exceptions" unchecked if the application is a mix of C#/C++.